# JavaScript reading input from USB HID

Tags: javascript, usb, positioning, hid

I am trying to change the position of a  trough USB-HID class inputs. Let's say I have a USB HID hardware that outputs 5 different values (1, 2, 3, 4 and 5). Based on which value is received the position of a  should change, so lets say for value "1" - new position is left: 100px;

Basically I alread have something like that using the arrow-keys (keyCode = 39 is position one). I first though I could just use the values my USB devices sends as keyCodes but that doe not work. How do I get those values into JavaScript?

Comment: Ok, let's clarify some things. I assume it's for client-side jS, right? How do you read or how do you plan to read your values from the USB-HID?

Comment: Sending keyboard event might not be a good idea, but using a middleware that will read the USB-HID (maybe nodejs + homemade module)  values and send them back to your JS (e.g trough ajax) would be a better solution.

I use that kind of solution to read my Raspberry Pi GPIO pins values.